# Why C++ does not have a convenient way to dynamically allocate memory for multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In C++, I feel very inconvenient that C++ does not have a built-in feature to dynamically allocate memory for multidimensional arrays in the run-time.

In Java, we can just do by one line of code. For example, in Java, we can dynamically allocate memory for a 4D integer-array with

```
int a, b, c, d;
std::cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
int[ ][ ][ ][ ] array = new int[a][b][c][d];
```

I googled the solutions to do the same thing in C++. But I found, in C++, we have to use nested loops, containers or some structures with functions to achieve the same thing. Since such syntax feature will be very handy, I want to ask why C++ did not incorporate such a built-in feature?

Comment: Interesting fun fact: that 4D array in Java? It isn't a 4D array. It an array of arrays of arrays of arrays of integers. It can be painfully slow because there is no connection between each dynamically allocated sub array. The CPU bounces around from one allocation to the next and never manages to pick up the speed it can get from contiguous data all preloaded into cache. The horrible nested loop C++ solution does the same thing, and it is horrible. Unless you need jagged arrays, don't do it in either language. Make a wrapper around a 1D array that handles the indexing for you.

Comment: Here's an example: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++ you can also allocate memory such a way. For example :)

```
auto array = new int[3][4][5][6];
```

or that is the same

```
int ( *array )[4][5][6] = new int[3][4][5][6];
```

Or you can use a typedef like

```
typedef int T[4][5][6];
// or
// using T = int[4][5][6];

T *array = new T[3];
```

The problem is that the expressions in the squares except the leftmost must be constant expressions.

Comment: Another problem is that it have a tendency to leak memory, when you for example, exit in an unusual way

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that we can use auto. So the auto type here will be the same as int * array[ ][ ][ ] ? Your answer is really helpful! But is there a way to do this by using non-constant expressions in the run-time? Most of time, I don't need to use multidimensional arrays. But I decide to learn C++ well, and want to know more details about it. Thus, my second question is that what context is proper to use multidimensional arrays? Do we always need to avoid them?

Comment: @HanM See my updated post. I showed alternative declarations. Unfortunately the expressions must be constant. So instead of arrays when the number of elements is not known at the compile time there are used usually standard containers  like std::vector in C++ .

Answer (score 2):

First of, never use `new`. There are better alternatives for everything.

Step zero, proper includes

```
#include <gsl/multi_span>
#include <memory>
```

Step one, set the dimensions

```
constexpr int x_sz = 3;
constexpr int y_sz = 4;
constexpr int z_sz = 5;
constexpr int total = x_sz * y_sz * z_sz;
```

Step two, allocate memory

```
auto arrptr = std::make_unique<int[]>( total );
```

Step three, create an array view

```
gsl::multi_span<int, x_sz, y_sz, z_sz> arr3d { arrptr.get(), total };
```

Congratulation, you have a bounds-checked three-dimensional array 
that will deallocate itself when it goes out of scope.

You can find GSL [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/)

Comment: Thanks! Is the GSL still not finished yet? I plan to read that when it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

We can also create a 2D rectangular array of size (M,N) as

```
auto array = (int (*)[N]) new int [ M*N ];
```

and a 3D array of size (L,M,N) as

```
auto array = (int (*)[M][N]) new int [ L*M*N ];
```

etc (where L, M, N,... can be variables). Defining a macro for this may be convenient. Also, if the size is small, we can simply do as

```
int array[M][N];
```

(I learned this before from Stackoverflow, thanks much!)

Comment: "int array[M][N]" has no worry about leak because it is allocated on the stack (correct?), but using raw "new" and pointers has the risk of leak; so I guess it is practically better (safer) to use some existing container class or fast libraries for multi-dim arrays, particularly for numerical calculations.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to C++, and not sure about what are the meanings of (int (*)[N]) and (int (*)[M][N]). They seem like types. But I am not sure how to correctly understand them. They also seem like generic expressions.

Comment: @HanM Hi, it is not at all a special thing, it is just type casting to a pointer to a rectangular array (see the second example of Vlad above also). If you find some better ways for multi-dim arrays, please let me know also :)